# Regression with ARIMA Errors for non-stationary timeseries: Mixing of stationary/non-stationary covariates?

Tags: r, regression, forecasting, arima, stationarity

Given I want to forecast e.g. monthly sales (dependent variable, likely non-stationary) with regression and ARIMA errors (ARIMA in R with xreg) I have e.g. two independent variables/covariates:

- Holidays per month (stationary)
- GDP or similar (non-stationary)

In R an ARIMA(p,1,q) will automatically difference the covariates automatically as well - could that be an issue, given one variable is already stationary? If yes, how could it be avoided?

Edit: I would like to avoid to check for stationarity and do differencing manually - as it gets ugly/tedious especially with seasonality. So far I'm using mostly the auto.arima from the forecast package with some restrictions.

Comment: It is definitely necessary to difference all independent variables if you have to difference dependent variable. See the link under "non stationary".  https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/

Comment: Yes, I read everything from Mr. Hyndman who as far as I know even filed a bugreport (accepted) for the basic R arima to difference all independent variables when d > 0. But I never saw any explicit example or mention of a stationary/non-stationary mix. As far as I understand you its not hurting, when the stationary variable gets differenced as well?

Comment: That is correct, you don't have a choice you HAVE to difference all the variables if your dependent variable is non stationary. If you use auto.arima then it is regression with arima errors.  No need to difference beforehand everything is handled automatically

Comment: I think it might hurt if you difference stationary variables. There is a well-known notion of overdifferencing. I would think twice before mechanically differencing anything that is not integrated in the first place.

Comment: As @forecaster said It is necessary to IDENTIFY the relationship by suitably differencing (possibly different) all series in the model. If Y and X are themselves non-stationary  the final model can still be Y= a + bX as compared to a potentially bloated model containing differencing factors. This is why AUTOBOX ( a piece of software that I have helped to develop) allows an option in this regard. Some very bad implementations e.g. SAS force unnecessary differencing into the TF MODEL.. A careful look at the TF schemes in the back of the B-J text will help.

Comment: Wait, why does it matter if regressors are stationary? 

I think if you are doing regression with arima errors, only the residuals from the initial regression are going through arima, so only the residuals have to be stationary. The regression part is only removing trends from the dependent variable. And, if there is co-seasonality between the independent and dependent variable,  I think in that case you can use seasonal dummies in the regression.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As @forecaster said It is necessary to IDENTIFY the relationship by suitably differencing (possibly different) all series in the model. If Y and X are themselves non-stationary  the final model can still be Y= a + bX as compared to a potentially bloated model containing differencing factors. This is why AUTOBOX ( a piece of software that I have helped to develop) allows an option in this regard. Some very bad implementations e.g. SAS force unnecessary differencing into the TF MODEL.. A careful look at the TF schemes in the back of the B-J text will help. @Richard Hardy is quite correct with his reflection that care must be taken . .

Comment: For regression with arima errors, for the regression part, why does it matter if anything is stationary or not? Am I right that only the errors need to be stationary, since you are performing arima analysis on the errors? 

But for the independent and dependent variables in the regression part of the process, does stationarity matter?

Comment: after adjusting y for x and any identified deterministic structure the remaining structure must  be stationary.